# oracle join creating duplicate records

Tags: sql, oracle, join

My query giving duplicate records. I want all the records in trip_checkpoint_event table and the corresponding values from other table.

**trip_hdr** is my main table
**trip_dtl_assign** is my details table
**TRIP_CHECKPOINT** table handle some details, **trip_checkpoint_event** table is corresponding details table for **trip_checkpoint**.

```
SELECT * FROM TRIP_HDR WHERE TRIP_HDR_ID LIKE '166'
SELECT * FROM TRIP_DTL_ASSIN WHERE TRIP_HDR_ID LIKE '166'
SELECT * FROM TRIP_CHECKPOINT WHERE TRIP_HDR_ID LIKE '166'
SELECT * FROM trip_checkpoint_event WHERE CHECKPOINT_ID IN ('279','280','282')
SELECT * FROM trip_checkpoint_event WHERE CHECKPOINT_ID IN (
SELECT CHECKPOINT_ID FROM TRIP_CHECKPOINT WHERE TRIP_HDR_ID LIKE '166' )
```

Below is my query, I can't figure out where I am doing wrong join

```
SELECT CHECKPOINT_EVT_ID,
       CKPT.TRIPCODE,
       CKPT.PROVIDER,
       CKPT.TRUCK BRV,
       CKPT.MASTER_DEVICE ,
       CASE
         WHEN SENSORID IS NULL THEN ' '
         ELSE SENSORID
       END SENSOR,
       CASE
         WHEN trip_checkpoint_event.TIMESTAMP = '0' THEN ' '  
         ELSE TS_GMT(trip_checkpoint_event.TIMESTAMP)  
       END SENSOR_OPEN_TIME, 
       CASE
         WHEN CKPT.TIMESTAMP = '0' THEN ' '   
         ELSE TS_GMT (CKPT.TIMESTAMP)  
       END DATE_OF_DELIVERY,  
       CASE
         WHEN CKPT.VOLUME IS NULL THEN 0 
         ELSE CKPT.VOLUME 
       END VOLUME , 
       CASE 
          WHEN CKPT.PLANNED_CP = '1' THEN 'PLANNED'  
          WHEN CKPT.PLANNED_CP = '0' THEN 'UNPLANNED'  
          ELSE 'Other'
       END PLANNED_CP_name, 
       CKPT.GEOZONE_CODE Delivery_point,
       CKPT.TNXID TNXID,
       CKPT.ORDERNO ORDERNO,
       CKPT.PROVIDER,
       CKPT.OMC OMC,
       CKPT.ENTRY_DATE ENTRY_DATE,
       CKPT.ORIGINATION ORIGINATION,
       CKPT.BD Begin_Journey_Date,
       CKPT.ED End_Journey_Date,
       CKPT.TRANSPORTATION_TYPE 
  FROM trip_checkpoint_event
  LEFT JOIN (***Select Checkpoint_ID,
                    TRIP_HDR_ID,
                    HDR.ASGNID,
                    HDR.SUBDIVID,
                    HDR.TRIPCODE,
                    HDR.BEGINDATE BD,
                    HDR.ENDDATE ED, 
                    HDR.MASTERID MASTERID,
                    HDR.SUBDEVICE SUBDEVICE,
                    HDR.MASTER_DEVICE MASTER_DEVICE,
                    HDR.SUB_DEVICE SUB_DEVICE,
                    GEOZONE_CODE,
                    VOLUME,
                    TIMESTAMP,
                    PLANNED_CP,
                    HDR.TIMEZONE ZONE,
                    HDR.truck_code TRUCK,
                    HDR.DEVICE_STATUS,
                    HDR.SUB_DEVICE_STATUS,
                    HDR.TNXID TNXID,
                    HDR.PROVIDER PROVIDER,
                    HDR.OMC OMC,
                    HDR.ORDERNO ORDERNO,
                    HDR.ORIGINATION ORIGINATION,
                    HDR.ENTRY_DATE ENTRY_DATE, 
                    CASE
                      WHEN (HDR.trip_type = '1' AND HDR.prime_type = '2') THEN '1' 
                      ELSE HDR.trip_type
                    END AS trip_type,  
                   CASE
                     WHEN trip_type = '1' THEN 'Prime Mover' 
                     WHEN trip_type = '2' THEN 'Fuel Truck' 
                     WHEN trip_type = '3' THEN 'Transit Vehicle' 
                     WHEN trip_type = '4' THEN 'BLC on Rail' 
                     WHEN trip_type = '5' THEN 'Container on Rail' 
                     WHEN trip_type = '6' THEN 'Close Truck'
                     ELSE 'Other' 
                   END TRANSPORTATION_TYPE 
               from trip_checkpoint
               LEFT JOIN (Select TH.TRIP_CODE TRIPCODE,
                                 TD.TRIP_ASGN_ID ASGNID,
                                 TD.DEVICE_ID,
                                 TD.SUB_DEVICE_ID SUBDIVID,
                                 TH.TRIP_HDR_ID as TRIP,
                                 TD.BEGIN_JOURNEY_DATE BEGINDATE,
                                 TD.OPEN_DATE ENDDATE,
                                 TD.DEVICE_ID MASTERID,
                                 TD.SUB_DEVICE_ID SUBDEVICE,
                                 (SELECT DEVICE_code FROM DEVICE WHERE DEVICE.DEVICE_ID = TD.DEVICE_ID) AS MASTER_DEVICE, 
                                 (SELECT DEVICE_code FROM DEVICE WHERE DEVICE.DEVICE_ID = TD.SUB_DEVICE_ID) AS SUB_DEVICE,  
                                 (SELECT truck_code FROM truck trk WHERE trk.truck_id = TD.truck_id) truck_code, 
                                 (SELECT TIMEZONE FROM account_key acc_key WHERE acc_key.ID = TH.account_id) TIMEZONE,  
                                 (SELECT PROVIDER_NAME FROM ASC_PROVIDER PROV WHERE PROV.PROVIDER_ID = TH.PROVIDER_ID) PROVIDER,  
                                 (SELECT COMPANY_NAME FROM ASC_COMPANY CMP WHERE CMP.COMPANY_ID = TH.COMPANY_ID) 
                                 OMC,
                                 th.regime_code TNXID,
                                 th.agent_pin ORDERNO,
                                 TH.TRIP_DATE ENTRY_DATE,
                                 TH.ORIGINATION ORIGINATION,
                                 TH.trip_type,
                                 TH.prime_type, 
                                 TD.DEVICE_STATUS,
                                 TD.SUB_DEVICE_STATUS 
                            from TRIP_DTL_ASSIGN TD,
                                 TRIP_HDR TH
                            WHERE TH.TRIP_HDR_ID = TD.TRIP_HDR_ID) HDR   
                 ON HDR.TRIP = trip_checkpoint.TRIP_HDR_ID
               WHERE HDR.TRIP = trip_checkpoint.TRIP_HDR_ID***) CKPT 
    ON trip_checkpoint_event.CHECKPOINT_ID = CKPT.Checkpoint_ID
    WHERE PLANNED_CP != 9
```

Here is the test data

```
1.SELECT trip_hdr_id,trip_code FROM TRIP_HDR WHERE TRIP_HDR_ID LIKE '166'
    166 TRN20191106-0002

    2.SELECT TRIP_HDR_ID,TRIP_ASGN_ID FROM TRIP_DTL_ASSIGN WHERE TRIP_HDR_ID LIKE '166'
    TRIP_HDR_ID TRIP_ASGN_ID
    166           271
    166           272

    3.SELECT CHECKPOINT_ID,TRIP_HDR_ID FROM TRIP_CHECKPOINT WHERE TRIP_HDR_ID LIKE '166'

    CHECKPOINT_ID    TRIP_HDR_ID 
    279               166
    280               166
    281               166
    282               166

    4.SELECT CHECKPOINT_EVT_ID,CHECKPOINT_ID FROM trip_checkpoint_event WHERE CHECKPOINT_ID IN ('279','280','281','282')

    CHECKPOINT_EVT_ID CHECKPOINT_ID
    133               282
    134               280
My expected result

 CHECKPOINT_EVT_ID CHECKPOINT_ID
    133               282
    134               280
```

When I run my full query as given above below is the result which has duplicates.I know it is the problem with join. Don't know how to correct it.

```
CHECKPOINT_EVT_ID CHECKPOINT_ID
    133               282
    133               282
    134               280    
    134               280
```

This section is generating the duplicates
*

```
Select Checkpoint_ID,
                        TRIP_HDR_ID,
                        HDR.ASGNID,
                        HDR.SUBDIVID,
                        HDR.TRIPCODE,
                        HDR.BEGINDATE BD,
                        HDR.ENDDATE ED, 
                        HDR.MASTERID MASTERID,
                        HDR.SUBDEVICE SUBDEVICE,
                        HDR.MASTER_DEVICE MASTER_DEVICE,
                        HDR.SUB_DEVICE SUB_DEVICE,
                        GEOZONE_CODE,
                        VOLUME,
                        TIMESTAMP,
                        PLANNED_CP,
                        HDR.TIMEZONE ZONE,
                        HDR.truck_code TRUCK,
                        HDR.DEVICE_STATUS,
                        HDR.SUB_DEVICE_STATUS,
                        HDR.TNXID TNXID,
                        HDR.PROVIDER PROVIDER,
                        HDR.OMC OMC,
                        HDR.ORDERNO ORDERNO,
                        HDR.ORIGINATION ORIGINATION,
                        HDR.ENTRY_DATE ENTRY_DATE, 
                        CASE
                          WHEN (HDR.trip_type = '1' AND HDR.prime_type = '2') THEN '1' 
                          ELSE HDR.trip_type
                        END AS trip_type,  
                       CASE
                         WHEN trip_type = '1' THEN 'Prime Mover' 
                         WHEN trip_type = '2' THEN 'Fuel Truck' 
                         WHEN trip_type = '3' THEN 'Transit Vehicle' 
                         WHEN trip_type = '4' THEN 'BLC on Rail' 
                         WHEN trip_type = '5' THEN 'Container on Rail' 
                         WHEN trip_type = '6' THEN 'Close Truck'
                         ELSE 'Other' 
                       END TRANSPORTATION_TYPE 
                   from trip_checkpoint
                   LEFT JOIN (Select TH.TRIP_CODE TRIPCODE,
                                     TD.TRIP_ASGN_ID ASGNID,
                                     TD.DEVICE_ID,
                                     TD.SUB_DEVICE_ID SUBDIVID,
                                     TH.TRIP_HDR_ID as TRIP,
                                     TD.BEGIN_JOURNEY_DATE BEGINDATE,
                                     TD.OPEN_DATE ENDDATE,
                                     TD.DEVICE_ID MASTERID,
                                     TD.SUB_DEVICE_ID SUBDEVICE,
                                     (SELECT DEVICE_code FROM DEVICE WHERE DEVICE.DEVICE_ID = TD.DEVICE_ID) AS MASTER_DEVICE, 
                                     (SELECT DEVICE_code FROM DEVICE WHERE DEVICE.DEVICE_ID = TD.SUB_DEVICE_ID) AS SUB_DEVICE,  
                                     (SELECT truck_code FROM truck trk WHERE trk.truck_id = TD.truck_id) truck_code, 
                                     (SELECT TIMEZONE FROM account_key acc_key WHERE acc_key.ID = TH.account_id) TIMEZONE,  
                                     (SELECT PROVIDER_NAME FROM ASC_PROVIDER PROV WHERE PROV.PROVIDER_ID = TH.PROVIDER_ID) PROVIDER,  
                                     (SELECT COMPANY_NAME FROM ASC_COMPANY CMP WHERE CMP.COMPANY_ID = TH.COMPANY_ID) 
                                     OMC,
                                     th.regime_code TNXID,
                                     th.agent_pin ORDERNO,
                                     TH.TRIP_DATE ENTRY_DATE,
                                     TH.ORIGINATION ORIGINATION,
                                     TH.trip_type,
                                     TH.prime_type, 
                                     TD.DEVICE_STATUS,
                                     TD.SUB_DEVICE_STATUS 
                                from TRIP_DTL_ASSIGN TD,
                                     TRIP_HDR TH
                                WHERE TH.TRIP_HDR_ID = TD.TRIP_HDR_ID) HDR   
                     ON HDR.TRIP = trip_checkpoint.TRIP_HDR_ID
                   WHERE HDR.TRIP = trip_checkpoint.TRIP_HDR_ID
```

*

Comment: Why negative vote ? Two days I am trying this query . I am not expert in sql that is why I asked the experts here . Thanks

Comment: you must be missing a join somewhere.  My suggestion is to "strip down" the query to remove some of the tables/joins, then start adding back, and see what you get.

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button below the tags and include 1) test data for all tables involved, 2) the results you're getting, and 3) the results you expected. Without that we're just guessing. I *suspect* that at least one and probably more than one of the tables involved in this query have multiple records for TRIP_HDR_ID '166'. Thanks.

Comment: Your expected results shows two columns being returned - CHECKPOINT_EVT_ID and CHECKPOINT_ID - but the query in your question does not return these two columns. Please edit your question and show the query you're actually executing which produces the results shown. [For future reference, I've set up a dbfiddle with the data added in your last edit](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ba3b70ceda22479adc1a6a12065f5e65)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: but why are you storing numbers as varchar values?

Answer (score 0):

Row multiplication occurs when you join table `trip_dtl_assign`. There is no 1:1 relation between this table and next part.

This is your sample data:

```
with 
    trip_hdr(trip_hdr_id, trip_code) as (
      select 166, 'TRN20191106-0002' from dual),
    trip_dtl_assign(trip_hdr_id, trip_asgn_id) as ( 
      select 166, 271 from dual union all
      select 166, 272 from dual ),
    trip_checkpoint(checkpoint_id, trip_hdr_id) as (
      select 279, 166 from dual union all
      select 280, 166 from dual union all
      select 281, 166 from dual union all
      select 282, 166 from dual ),
    trip_checkpoint_event(checkpoint_evt_id, checkpoint_id) as (
      select 133, 282 from dual union all
      select 134, 280 from dual)
```

and this is your very simplified query:

```
select th.trip_hdr_id, trip_code, trip_asgn_id, checkpoint_evt_id, tcp.checkpoint_id 
  from trip_hdr              th 
  join trip_dtl_assign       tda on tda.trip_hdr_id = th.trip_hdr_id
  join trip_checkpoint       tcp on tcp.trip_hdr_id = th.trip_hdr_id
  join trip_checkpoint_event tce on tce.checkpoint_id = tcp.checkpoint_id
```

I tried with your original SQL and reduced logic to above. The result is:

```
TRIP_HDR_ID TRIP_CODE        TRIP_ASGN_ID CHECKPOINT_EVT_ID CHECKPOINT_ID
----------- ---------------- ------------ ----------------- -------------
        166 TRN20191106-0002          271               134           280
        166 TRN20191106-0002          272               134           280
        166 TRN20191106-0002          271               133           282
        166 TRN20191106-0002          272               133           282
```

So why would Oracle assign id 271 to checkpoint 280 and id 272 to checkpoint 282 (or vice versa)? What is the logic here? If you answer this question you can add proper joining condition.
You can use `row_number()` twice to number rows:

```
row_number() over (partition by ... order by trip_asgn_id) r1,
row_number() over (partition by ... order by checkpoint_evt_id) r2
```

and then choose only rows where r1 = r2, but I don't know if this is what you want.